# Unable to start Apache on CentOS Private Key Not Found

Tags: apache, ssl, centos, private-key

I am unable to start Apache on a CentOS Server with SELinux. The error log gives.

```
[root@server httpd]# cat test-error_log
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] Init: Private key not found
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218640442 error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 67710980 error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Nov 15 05:42:34 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
```

It fails here also

```
[root@server private]#  openssl rsa -in test.key -check -noout
unable to load Private Key
140598241089352:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
140598241089352:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=RSA
140598241089352:error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib:rsa_ameth.c:115:
140598241089352:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
140598241089352:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
140598241089352:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:pem_pkey.c:132:
```

The path is in the conf file

```
[root@server conf]# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/test.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@server.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test
ServerName server.server.com

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/test.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/test.key


ErrorLog logs/test-error_log
CustomLog logs/test-access_log common
```

I also checked there are no spaces in the Private Key. Any other ideas where this is going wrong?

Also

```
[root@server etc]#  ls -dZ /etc/pki/tls/private/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /etc/pki/tls/private/
[root@server etc]#  ls -dZ /etc/pki/tls/certs/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /etc/pki/tls/certs/
```

I have also checked there are no spaces in the Private Key and appropriate number of dashes.

EDIT: Output of ls -al /etc/pki/tls/private/ and ls -al /etc/pki/tls/certs/

```
[root@server ~]# ls -al /etc/pki/tls/certs/
total 1788
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 Nov 15 08:51 .
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root    4096 Feb 11  2015 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  786601 Jul 14  2014 ca-bundle.crt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1005005 Jul 14  2014 ca-bundle.trust.crt
-rw-------. 1 root root    1513 Feb 11  2015 localhost.crt
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     610 Jan 20  2015 make-dummy-cert
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    2242 Jan 20  2015 Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     829 Jan 20  2015 renew-dummy-cert
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    1208 Feb 11  2015 test.crt
-rw-------. 1 root root    3258 Nov 15 08:51 test_1.cert
[root@ip-10-155-16-219 ~]# ls -al /etc/pki/tls/private/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Nov 18 21:15 .
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 4096 Feb 11  2015 ..
-rw-------. 1 root root 1679 Feb 11  2015 localhost.key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1679 Nov 18 21:15 test.key
[root@server ~]#
```

Answer (score 1):

Is you private key encrypted?
To determine if your private key is encrypted:

```
grep ENCRYPTED /etc/pki/tls/private/test.key
```

If yes, remove the password from the private key:

```
openssl rsa -in /etc/pki/tls/private/test.key -out /etc/pki/tls/private/test-new.key
```

Check the header of your private key, should look like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And check the footer, should look like this:

```
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Remove any space or newline after the footer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Its not encrypted and I have already checked no spaces at beginning or end. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you list the content of  `ls -al /etc/pki/tls/certs/` and `ls -al /etc/pki/tls/private/` ?

Comment: Added on the main question.

Comment: Have you tried to re-generate your private and public keys?

Comment: I already have the certificate. Regenerating the private key will require sending CSR to CA to provide a certificate. Maybe I can use OpenSSL. Is there a absolutely 100% way to know if private key is not correct?

Comment: So I created an OpenSSL cert and key and the service started! The site is still not loading but I need to check on why. This proves that the private key was not correct. Is there any way to identify and fix a private key (I know it sound absurd but any steps that I might take?)

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen people pound out the line
**#SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt**

and they create a *new* line with their *newly generated* file:

**SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/somenewcert.crt**

Here is where the fun starts...they then copy this line down to the Key file section, and do this:

#SSLCertificate**Key**File /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key

**SSLCertificateFile** /etc/pki/tls/private/somenewkey.key

They get so busy editing the value for the key path, that they completely forget to change the SSLCertificateFile to SSLCertificate**Key**File when they copy it.

This happens a LOT. Apache should probably change these so that they are more different so people will notice this before pulling their hair out debugging the private key for hours before they finally figure this out.